# Use the same c# model twice in an EF database context

Tags: c#, entity-framework, orm, datamapper

We have an app where sets of a complex data model are held in a data store - we call the individual sets of data DataFiles. These DataFiles can be called into an editor to make changes and after that is done that are saved back to the store. The process is not unlike loading an Excel file from your hard drive, editing and then choosing to save or save as.

Our current App design separates the DataFile store and the DataFile editor into two databases and two database contexts. In this way we can use the same C# model for the store and the editor and can do some very simple mapping of the edited DataFile back to the store and vice versa. In the simplest case:

- get A
- A = B
- save B

This eliminates the need for 1:1 mapping of the properties. It also makes injection of A into B relatively easy for more complex data structures

We need to move to a single database context for both the store and the editor.

The question is - in a single database context, can we bind one C# data model to two separate data tables the database?

Here is a very simple example of what we are trying to do. This doesn't work because EF tries to map both DbSet definitions to the one table (called DataFile)

```
// C# model
namespace MyApp.Models
{
    public partial class DataFile
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public int MyDataField { get; set; }
        public string MyOtherDataField { get; set; }

    }
}

// Database binding
public class AppDbContext : DbContext
{
    public AppDbContext() : base("name=AppDbContext"){}

    // Store Data File Access
    public virtual DbSet<DataFile> StoreDataFiles { get; set; }

    // Active Data File Access
    public virtual DbSet<DataFile> EditorDataFiles { get; set; }


    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }

}
```

Comment: It seems that it is possible https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc716698%28v=vs.100%29.aspx Here's a nicer explanation http://blogs.msdn.com/b/simonince/archive/2009/03/23/mapping-two-tables-to-one-entity-in-the-entity-framework.aspx

Comment: That suggestion appears to cover the situation where the two tables combine together to cover all properties in the model. In our case the two database tables are replicates of each other and both map to all properties in the model.

Comment: Perhaps a naive suggestion but, are you sure you need two tables? What if, for example, you used an ID/GUID field to discriminate between two DataFiles with the same name?

Comment: Yes right back at the beginning we started with that approach but it gets awfully confusing in terms of where DataFiles exist and why. The way we have it now the store table only contains stored data. The editor table only contains current editable data. ... but you are on to something and maybe we can think about going back to the future with some additional properties that identify store and editor DataFiles

Comment: @Xcheque "maybe we can think about going back to the future"... I see what you did there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution which I think will give you what you need, the only caveat being that the ID field needs to be unique across *both* tables, and you'll need to handle that yourself. Other than that, this technique is derived from [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-3-table-per-concrete-type-tpc-and-choosing-strategy-guidelines) called 'Table Per Concrete Type'.

What we'll do is create an abstract class with the properties that your type has, and inherit from it. This should keep both classes in sync, and you can get one or the other by casting back and forth. The important thing here is the `DatabaseGeneratedAttribute` set to 'None'; using this technique, since both tables will have the same PK, EF can't tell that it needs to share them across tables.

The parent class has to be abstract; at least, this is the only way I could get it to recognize it as a DbSet but not create a table for it.

```
public abstract class DataFileParent
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public int MyDataField { get; set; }
        public string MyOtherDataField { get; set; }
    }

public class DataFileEditor : DataFileParent
    {
    }

public class DataFileStore : DataFileParent
    {
    }
```

Now we can create our `Context` class, with only a single `DbSet` that will be shared across the tables. We're also going to tell the context that we want to map Entities to different tables based on their concrete type, which is done in the `OnModelCreating` method.

```
public class Context : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<DataFileParent> DataFileParents { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<DataFileEditor>().Map(m =>
            {
                m.MapInheritedProperties();
                m.ToTable("DataFileEditor");
            });

            modelBuilder.Entity<DataFileStore>().Map(m =>
            {
                m.MapInheritedProperties();
                m.ToTable("DataFileStore");
            });
        }
    }
```

And that's pretty much it! Now when you want to create a `DataFileStore` or `DataFileEditor` you can do so, and add it like: (assuming `Store` is a variable of type `DataFileStore`)

```
using (var db = new Context())
{
    db.DataFileParents.Add(Store);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

I put together a little console app for this and put it up on [GitHub](https://github.com/DrewJordan/EntityFrameworkTPC).

Comment: This looks very promising! The console app seems to work. I will run up a test in our application environment and see what happens

Comment: Yep this is a winner. Some interesting challenges to keep all the ducks in a row but we definitely meet our objective of having a single model feeding into two tables in the same database. Well done and thanks for your quick and comprehensive response.

Comment: Turns out there is a snag with this method. The creation of two separate derived classes doesn't seem to allow us to equate one derived class to the other. We can't use the A = B method to copy what are quite complex DataFiles (lots of children). The solution we settled on was to use the suggested table mapping method and 2 separate contexts operating on one database - one for the Editor and one for the Store. With some careful EF mapping we can use a common DataFile Object for both Editor & Store - with the bonus that both database structures can be related back to the same user parent table.

Comment: ah, yeah... I guess it wouldn't. Glad to hear you figured it out.